# How to save string resources in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

How can i save a string that i use frequently in my ionic app. I know in android studio you can save them in the string folder and use them frequently. what is the ionic 3 equivalent to that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a constants file like `app.constants.ts`

```
export const appConst = {
    recordPerPage: 20,
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy
};
```

Then import in other pages like below

```
import { appConst } from './../../../app.constants';
```

You can use in code like `appConst.recordPerPage`

Comment: thanks mate. i believe this is what i was looking for

Comment: Glad to help you.